# Fullecalendar using resourceGroupField / resourceAreaColumns hiding events after collapse

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

**Initial view :**

[image: Initial view (before collapse):]

**After collapsing the groupings :**

[image: Collapsed:]

**After expansion :**

[image: Expanded:]

I just can't figure out why are the events not showing.
There is no refetching going on,
just seems like the events aren't being rendered. The weird part is that any resize of the entire window, the events are being rendered.

I've tried using the **cellDidMount** callback to refetch the events, it is fixing the problem, however this solution is very costly on the backend since it is making calls to fetch the events however many Resources exist on that grouping.

Comment: Can you inspect the emitted events thanks to your Vue devtools to see what is not working?

Comment: Nope, can't see anything relevant on Vue Dev tools.

Comment: You can probably call calendar.render() to force it to redraw properly

Comment: As I said, you can initiate calendar.render() within a specific event callback, like cellDidMount for example. This is leading to multiple calls which is very inefficient. If I have 100 resources, it will redraw the whole calendar with events 100 times.